# Xfinity Modem/Router Handing Out Strange IP Addresses

Tags: networking, router, ip, subnet

I have an Xfinity (Comcast) provided Modem/Router combo that's been acting strange recently. It's a DPC3941T manufactured by Cisco.

I have the router set on a 255.0.0.0 subnet with DHCP enabled for the addresses 10.0.0.1/24 and Wi-Fi is disabled. I have a Ubiquiti Unifi AP Lite for the Wi-Fi access throughout my home.

But what I have noticed recently is that the router seems to be handing out IP's on a completely different subnet. And all of these other IP's have no similarity other than the 10 at the start. Here is a screencap of the offending devices.[image]

None of the affected devices have restricted access. Speeds are the same as usual and I don't really have a way to determine if they are accessible from other subnets however, chromecasts still work.

Any ideas as to how to fix this? Or should I just let it be since nothing seems to be affected?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those addresses are all in the same network if your network mask is `255.0.0.0.`

Apparently you are unfamiliar with IPv4 subnetting. An IPv4 address is a 32-bit binary number. The dotted-decimal notation that you see is simply to make it easier for humans to read. To determine the network of an IPv4 address you simply perform a logical `AND` with the address and mask. If the result is the same among addresses, they are on the same network.

For example, one of the addresses about which you are concerned is `10.5.83.205`, but you are not concerned about the following address, `10.0.0.220`. The mask for both addresses is `255.0.0.0`. If you `AND` both addresses with the mask, you end up with the same network, so both addresses are on the same network:

```
10.5.83.205 is 00001010000001010101001111001101
255.0.0.0   is 11111111000000000000000000000000
           AND ================================
               00001010000000000000000000000000 = 10.0.0.0

10.0.0.220  is 00001010000000000000000011011100
255.0.0.0   is 11111111000000000000000000000000
           AND ================================
               00001010000000000000000000000000 = 10.0.0.0
```

Comment: Ahh I see! I apparently was quite unfamiliar with subnetting. So I imagine if I set my subnet mask to 255.255.255.0 then it should go back to what I am used to seeing? ie. 10.0.0.1-254?

Comment: Yes, but as I said, the dotted-decimal notation is only for human readability. Never depend on the octets. You may run into many different mask lengths. For instance, a 26-bit mask (`255.255.255.192`, or something like `10.0.0.0/26`) is not uncommon, and depending on the octets would lead you very far astray because there are actually four networks contained in the last octet.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for answering my question!